# Magento gender mass action (mr/mrs)

Tags: magento

Since the redesign of our store it is necessary to select the gender when creating a new customer account. The problem is that still old user accounts exist, which do not have a gender selected.

I'm trying to find a way (mass action) to select 'male' for all 'Mr' and 'female' for all 'Mrs'.
Does anyone have a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way to achieve this, is login to admin and go to;

```
System > Import/Export > Export
```

From the top menu.  Choose entity type 'customers', scroll to the bottom of the screen and click 'continue' to download all the customers.

Open the csv and set the gender column as you wish, save the file and then go to;

```
System > Import/Export > Import
```

Select entity type 'customers', append complex data.  Choose the new file, click check data and then click import.

The field values are the text value by the way, ie; Male or Female, case sensitive.

If you'd rather remove the field, which may be better - having to choose anything in signup/checkout is a ball ache for the end user if it's not necessary...

Go to;

```
System > Confguration
```

From the top menu, then go to;

```
Customers > Customer Configuration
```

From the left menu.  Then open the 'Name and Address Options' tab, and change 'Show Gender' to 'No'.

Comment: Thank you for that. Do I overwrite the existing customer data when I import the file or just set the new value?
Btw, there is a reason why gender is activated.

Comment: leave all the columns in place and it will update the existing records.  gender is an optional field for customers as it can useful for creating newsletters, but 99% of people have it switched off

Comment: Yes but we need it for our payment provider. Thank you again, I will test it.